# instantiate childclass via constructor param

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Im currently trying to implement an interface to create instances of sorting algorithms.

I have the following classes:
**ISortAlgorithm** -> abstract (interface" class)
**AlgorithmModule** -> with a static function ->

```
static ISortAlgorithm* CreateSortInstanceOf(EAlgorithm AlgorithmEnum)
```

And a class container (namespace Algorithms) with Subclasses of ISortAlgorithm like ->

```
class SelectionSort : public ISortAlgorithm
```

There also exists the enum for each implemented Algorithm ->

```
enum EAlgorithm {SELECTIONSORT, BUBBLESORT, ...}
```

During runtime someone who wants to use an algorithm from my module, he calls:

```
AlgorithmModule::CreateSortInstanceOf(/*enum of desired algorithm */)
```

The first thing i did within that function was ->

```
{
switch (enumparam)
{
case (EAlgorithm::INSERTSORT) :
        return SortAlgorithm = new Algorithms::InsertSort();
        break;
case (blah): [..]
}
```

This is working already. But now i think of a way to make that easier, i came up with the idea that i could use the constructor for this and tried:

```
class InsertSort : public ISortAlgorithm
{
public:
    InsertSort() : ISortAlgorithm(EAlgorithm::INSERTSORT){}
}

class SelectionSort : public ISortAlgorithm
{
public:
    SelectionSort() : ISortAlgorithm(EAlgorithm::SELECTIONSORT) {}
}
```

and additional to this i modified the  *CreateSortInstanceOf*  to:

```
static ISortAlgorithm* CreateSortInstanceOf(EAlgorithm AlgorithmEnum)
{
    ISortAlgorithm* SortAlgorithm = new ISortAlgorithm(AlgorithmEnum);  
    return SortAlgorithm;
}
```

So the intention would be, that to use the constructor param to call the right childclass. Would mean i dont have to alter the code for this function for any algorithm i want to implement in the future. However, of course the compiler complains about, that i cannot instantiate an abstract class and i think another problem is the non-inheritance of ctor´s.

But im sure, that my intention should be possible, so i need your help to point me to what im missing here.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It's a way to do what you want, even if it is not necessarily the nicest :

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "map"

    enum EAlgorithm { SELECTIONSORT=0, INSERTSORT=1 };

    class ISortAlgorithm;
    typedef ISortAlgorithm * (*fct)(void);
    std::map mapCreator;

    class ISortAlgorithm
    {
        public:
        ISortAlgorithm(void) {};
        virtual void run(void) = 0;
        static ISortAlgorithm* CreateSortInstanceOf(EAlgorithm AlgorithmEnum)
        {
            std::map::iterator it = mapCreator.find(AlgorithmEnum);
            if (it == mapCreator.end())
                return NULL;
            return it->second();
        }
    };

    class InsertSort : public ISortAlgorithm
    {
        public:
        InsertSort(){}
        virtual void run(void){};
        static ISortAlgorithm * Create(void)
        {
            return (ISortAlgorithm*) new InsertSort();
        };
    };

    class SelectionSort : public ISortAlgorithm
    {
        public:
        SelectionSort(){};
        virtual void run(void){};
        static ISortAlgorithm * Create(void)
        {
            return (ISortAlgorithm*) new SelectionSort();
        };
    };

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        mapCreator.insert(std::pair(EAlgorithm::INSERTSORT, InsertSort::Create));
        mapCreator.insert(std::pair(EAlgorithm::SELECTIONSORT, SelectionSort::Create));
        ISortAlgorithm * pt1 = ISortAlgorithm::CreateSortInstanceOf(EAlgorithm::INSERTSORT);
        ISortAlgorithm * pt2 = ISortAlgorithm::CreateSortInstanceOf(EAlgorithm::SELECTIONSORT);
        return 0;
    }
```